# Sql where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, json

i want to make a query with 3 relations table and i want to get the json format

```
product_type (parent)
      /     \
  product_type Addresses (child)
    /
product_brand (grandchild)
```

My relation in my query are good, but I got an error:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

and thats my query :

```
SELECT *,
   (SELECT *,
     (SELECT *
      FROM product_brand WHERE product_brand.product_type_id = product.product_id) as s
   FROM product WHERE product.product_type_id = product_type.product_type_id) as e
 FROM product_type ;
```

I need my response to look like this :

```
Data: [{
    product_type_name: "CAT1",
    product_type_details: "",
    product_type_image: "mobileapp/public/images/-98553543.png",
    items: [

        {
            product_name: "SUBCAT2 LAL CAT2",
            product_image: "mobileapp/public/images/",
            product_details: "&nbsp;SD",
            product_price: "",
            items: [{
                product_brand_name: "LAL SUBCAT2 LAL CAT2",
                product_brand_details: "&nbsp;SDSD",
                product_brand_image: "mobileapp/public/images/",
                product_brand_price: "442"
            }, {
                product_brand_name: "DFDF",
                product_brand_details: "&nbsp;DFDF",
                product_brand_image: "mobileapp/public/images/",
                product_brand_price: "13"
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Is there not an error in the sql? where is product_type Addresses?

Comment: Why do you nested subqueries like that?  Why not just use a `JOIN`?

Comment: Subqueries in the `SELECT` can only return one column.  You can't use `SELECT *` in the subquery.  It's trying to combine all those columns into one, and it can't.

Comment: You will probably need to end up doing a join on the product, product_type and product_brand tables, which I am assuming are tables based on your query.

Comment: Any exemple please to use join , am using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know the data structure of the tables. I am guessing it based on your query and the expected data. Your query implies to me that your data is not normalized as well as it could be. If product is a child of product_type, and product_brand is a child of product, then product_brand doesn't need product_type_id, as it can determine it through the relationships.

To answer your question, you should JOIN the tables, as Rocket suggested. Here is an example of a nested join query that should return the results you want, assuming my guess about your table structure is correct.

```
SELECT pt.name, pt.details, pt.image,
    p.name, p.image, p.details, p.price,
    pb.name, pb.details, pb.image, pb.price
FROM product_type AS pt
INNER JOIN product AS p ON p.product_type_id = pt.product_type_id
INNER JOIN product_brand AS pb ON p.product_id = pb.product_id
```

Comment: Hello ,  thanks for ur query , it works fine, but how i can modify it to show also the product_type if theres no child ( product) thanks

Comment: You can use LEFT JOIN for that.

`SELECT pt.name, pt.details, pt.image,
    p.name, p.image, p.details, p.price,
    pb.name, pb.details, pb.image, pb.price
FROM product_type AS pt
LEFT JOIN product AS p ON p.product_type_id = pt.product_type_id
LEFT JOIN product_brand AS pb ON p.product_id = pb.product_id`

This query will make it so you will always get product_type, even if there is no product, and you will get the product even if there is no brand.

Comment: I tried it bro , and it didn't works i dont know why

Comment: Did you get an error, or did you get different results than what you wanted?

Comment: i got the same result as if i used INNER JOIN  ,theres no difference

Comment: You might need to look at your data. Basically, a LEFT JOIN will include all records from the table on the left side of the join (product_type), and if there are records that match in the table on the right side, it will include them. If not, it will return NULL for the fields in the right table. You can find more detail about LEFT JOIN here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: i've used : $result =mysql_query($sql);
  and while($response = mysql_fetch_object($result ))
it can be the reason ?

Comment: That shouldn't affect the results. I recommend looking at the data and the relationships and reading the article on SQL LEFT JOIN.

Comment: i've added to my query where pb.lang_id = 1 and p.lang_id  = 1 and pt.lang_id = 1, thats why it doesnt return null  fields, how can i make a condition for this  query